# Animation according to the rotation around the character

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I currently have a character who can move in different directions, for each direction a different animation is launched. The movement is currently done using the keys.

I would like that depending on the angle of the mouse around the character the meaning of the animation also changes.

[image]
[image]

I need that depending on the angle of the mouse, the animation of the direction starts. As the example below.

[image]

```
[Header("Movement")]
[Tooltip("Walk movement")]
public float speed = 5f;
[Tooltip("Player Rigidbody")]
public Rigidbody2D rigidBody;
public Animator animator;

Vector2 movement;

void FixedUpdate() {

    // Position
    movement.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    movement.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

    // Animations
    animator.SetFloat("Horizontal", movement.x);
    animator.SetFloat("Vertical", movement.y);
    animator.SetFloat("Vitesse", movement.sqrMagnitude);

    // Angle isometric
    if (movement.x != 0  && movement.y != 0)
    {
        movement.y = movement.y / 2;
    }

    Vector2 inputVector = new Vector2(movement.x, movement.y);
    inputVector = Vector2.ClampMagnitude(inputVector, 1);
    Vector2 movement = inputVector * speed;

    // Movement
    rigidBody.MovePosition(rigidBody.position + movement * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
}
```

If anyone has a lead or an example, I thank you in advance.

Comment: *"I need"* is a poor question. *"I can't do <concrete thing here>"* is a much better one.

Comment: What I wrote is not clear enough for you?

Comment: The question should not be edited to include an answer. Please post the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I basically did below is calculate angle between cursor and player then set the animations accordingly.
if you have questions or need clarification just reply but I feel like the code might work even if you simply put it in your `Update` function. `Input.mousePosition` may not readily work for 2D in that case you can just switch it up with `Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition)`. Good luck!

```
//direction towards cursor
Vector2 towardCursor = Input.mousePosition - transform.position;


//angle between worldspace right and direction towards cursor
//signedAngle to detect negative angles
float angleVertical = Vector2.SignedAngle(Transform.right, towardCursor);

//angle between worldspace up and direction towards cursor
float angleHorizontal = Vector2.SignedAngle(Transform.up, towardCursor);

//reversed to make clockwise angles negative angles        
angleVertical = -angleVertical;
angleHorizontal = -angleHorizontal;

if (angleVertical > 90
||
angleVertical < -90)
{

angleVertical = angleVertical > 0 ? 180 - angleVertical : -180 - angleVertical;

}

if (angleHorizontal > 90
||
angleHorizontal < -90)
{

angleHorizontal = angleHorizontal > 0 ? 180 - angleHorizontal : -180 - angleHorizontal;

}

animator.setFloat("Vertical", angleVertical / 90);
animator.setFloat("Horizontal", angleHorizontal / 90);
```

Comment: I succeeded by modifying as you announced on Input.mousePosition. But the animations are upside down

Comment: ohh my bad, forget reversing the angles then, sorry for late reply.

Comment: It does not matter, thank you for the answers. So I already tried to reverse the angles but it doesn't work.

Comment: no no not reversing the angles (horizontal with vertical) I meant the part where I made both angles negative I'm saying keep them positive then it'll work.

Comment: I add
Vector3 mouse = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

And remove
angleVertical = -angleVertical;
angleHorizontal = -angleHorizontal;

But I still have the same problem.

Comment: Alright then last attempt would be to inverse Transfrom.right & Transform.up just make the negative they'll return left & down vectors. Good luck and I hope I pointed you in the right way as you requested and perhaps you may even give me that sweet sweet green tick :) thanks.

Comment: it works by inverting only the transform.up vector. Thanks for your help.